# I got soap reponse and i dont know how to bind it to listview it includes images also please help me?

Tags: android, listview

This is My Soap Method

public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
        {
           SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://guatsin.com/DesktopModules/WebServices/", "CategoriasBO_ObtenerTodos");

```
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.dotNet=true;
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

       System.out.println("Request"+request.toString());


       HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.guatsin.com/desktopmodules/webservices/default.asmx");  
       httpTransport.debug = true; 
       httpTransport.call("http://guatsin.com/DesktopModules/WebServices/CategoriasBO_ObtenerTodos", envelope);
       System.out.println("--------------req "+httpTransport.requestDump);
       System.out.println("--------------res "+httpTransport.responseDump);
       SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; 

       SoapObject element=(SoapObject) result.getProperty("CategoriasBO_ObtenerTodosResult");
       System.out.println("--------------element "+element.toString());

       return result;
    }
```

From the above i Got the response like this

07-11 18:48:52.134: INFO/System.out(252): --------------res 

    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            8
                            Bar & Restaurants
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home8.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/bar-restaurants1.png
                            true
                        
                        
                            9
                            Fashion & Beauty
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home7.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/fashion-beauty2.png
                            true
                        
                        
                            10
                            Party & Entertainment
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home2.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/party-entertainment2.png
                            true
                        
                        
                            11
                            Life & Style
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home3.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/life-style1.png
                            true

07-11 18:48:52.134: INFO/System.out(252): --------------res 

    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            8
                            Bar & Restaurants
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home8.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/bar-restaurants1.png
                            true
                        
                        
                            9
                            Fashion & Beauty
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home7.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/fashion-beauty2.png
                            true
                        
                        
                            10
                            Party & Entertainment
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home2.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/party-entertainment2.png
                            true
                        
                        
                            11
                            Life & Style
                            /desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home3.png
                            desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/life-style1.png
                            true

How can i parse this data to listview i want to display category name and one image into list view

please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in appropriate data structure. Use XML or JSON or something else. It would be very easy to parse it after that.